# How to Filter Data in SQL Without Using Group By / Having Functions

Tags: sql, group-by, common-table-expression, partition-by

Have a situation where I'm trying to produce a query that shows the item # on a sales order and the total outstanding quantity across all orders. I can do this as follows:

```
SELECT 
SL.[Item No_], 
SUM(SL.[Outstanding Quantity]) 

FROM [Database$Sales Header] SH
LEFT JOIN [Database$Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
LEFT JOIN [Database$Items] I ON I.[No_] = SL.[Item No_]

GROUP BY 
SL.[Item No_], 
SH.[Document Type], 
I.[Product Code]

HAVING
SH.[Document Type] = '1'
AND I.[Product Code] = 'SHIRT'

ORDER BY
SL.[Item No_]
```

Above code gives me a simple summary of item # and qty. on all sales orders.
I'm using the HAVING clause to include only sales orders (Document Type)
and only items that are shirts (Product Code).

The issue I'm having is when I want to exclude a particular customer.

I tried adding: AND SH.[Customer No_] <> 'CUST1' to the HAVING clause but if I do that, then SQL will require me to add it in the GROUP BY clause. The result is I get duplicate rows where it was summarized before because now SQL is reporting on outstanding quantity by item # and customer # which is not what I want.

So I am not sure how to exclude that customer without putting it into GROUP BY.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `HAVING` at all... `HAVING` is like `WHERE` but for aggregated values e.g. `COUNT`/`MAX`/`MIN` for a simple condition like you are using it should all be `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use where clause to filter the data.

```
SELECT 
SL.[Item No_], 
SUM(SL.[Outstanding Quantity]) 

FROM [Database$Sales Header] SH
LEFT JOIN [Database$Sales Line] SL ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.[No_]
LEFT JOIN [Database$Items] I ON I.[No_] = SL.[Item No_]

where SH.[Customer No_] <> 'CUST1' 

GROUP BY 
SL.[Item No_], 
SH.[Document Type], 
I.[Product Code]

HAVING
SH.[Document Type] = '1'
AND I.[Product Code] = 'SHIRT'

ORDER BY
SL.[Item No_]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, didn't realize at the time I could use both WHERE and HAVING clause both. thanks again.

Comment: You are most welcome @adhocEY. Best wishes.

Comment: And in fact the existing `HAVING` clause should be moved to `WHERE` because its not using a aggregate function.